# Posicion y tamaño botones PYQT

Tags: python, botón, pyqt

Necesito cambiar el tamaño de los botones de mi codigo. Uso PYQT4 y python 2.7

```
class Form(QDialog):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      self.b1 = QPushButton("DK new tags")
      self.b1.setCheckable(True)
      self.b1.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b1))
      self.b1.clicked.connect(self.DesktopWeb)
      layout.addWidget(self.b1)
      self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Has probado con el metodo setGeometry?

Comment: si pero no cambia nada, no se porque no sucede nada cada vez que lo escribo! Tambien probe con el metodo move() y nada

Comment: ¿Quieres modificar el alto o el ancho? Ten en cuenta que usas un BoxLayout y es el el encargado de modificar el tamaño de los widget que contiene de forma dinámica, en función del tamaño de la ventana. En estos casos agregar un esquema de como quieres que quede todo (no solo este botón sino todo el Dialog) es de gran ayuda.

Comment: No se como se hace eso. Lo unico que necesito es mover para la derecha el boton move(100). Nada mas!

Comment: Establece un tamaño fijo como por ejemplo `self.b1.setFixedSize(100, 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Hermano lo que yo le recomiendo es que actualice la versión de Python mejor (Por lo menos a la versión 3) y pruebe con el método:

```
self.b1.setGeometry(
    "longitud en x", 
    "longitud en y", 
    "tamaño de b1 en x", 
    "tamaño de b1 en y"
)
```